Override current code with specific changelog
I need to discard any changes of code and restore the code as a previous changelog.
For example I want to discard T2, T3 and T4 and return to T1.
Searching on google I found only this command:
git reset --hard T1

but when I try to push, it says my branch is behind and forces me to merge T2, T3 and T4.
I just want to restart from a previous commit.


If you really want to get rid of later commits in the remote branch, you need to do a force-push by adding  -f as an option when pushing.

"My question is simple." ...no question asked, neither in the title nor in the question body. *sigh*

@RomainValeri That's how simple it is. No question can be simpler than a nonexisting question.

Maybe take a look at this near duplicate if you're unsure about how to apply or understand eftshift0's (perfectly accurate) advice.

@dan1stmightbehappyagain :-D Some comments are priceless! That was a good one.

Do you want T2, T3, T4 to still appear in the history or not?

Although there are good answers on how to force the reset I think is important to say that  "forcing" might not always be a good idea, probably git revert would be easier to handle (if it's ok for you to have T2,3,4 in your history) this answer gives some detail, but you ay as well go to the documentation of git revert

Something like git revert HEAD~2 could be very easy to handle (choosing the right number of commits)

@Ivan How is reverting 3 commits anti-chronogically easier than a reset? Even if successful it'll mess history for no reason. git revert is a good alternative when you can't easily change history (i.e. coworkers involved because it's a remote shared branch).

@Ivan my answer actually covers that approach too, and with Romain's acknowledgements about remote shared branches.

@RomainValeri for example, if commits T2, T3 and T4 were pushed, and someone pulled them and kept working it can be very painful to reset. But it depends on each case.

The message you're talking about should be
Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
Since you've reset your local history, but some of those changes have already been pushed before, Git is preventing you from losing those commits on the remote. In fact, Git cannot tell the difference between a case where you're simply behind or a scenario where you've decided to reset your local history to a previous point and update the remote as well.
Reset & Push Force Approach
In this situation, as @eftshift0 has already said in the comments, you should force the push to the remote with a git push --force <remote> <branch>. Like so, you're telling Git that you're sure of the history you're pushing and to override what's currently on the remote's branch.
#Resetting to T1
git reset --hard HEAD~3

#Foricing the push to the remote
git push --force

However, you should perform such an operation only if you're absolutely sure that nobody else in your team has already based their work on those commits. Otherwise, their commit history would branch from an unreachable point of your branch, making the reconciliation quite messy and definitely not doable with a simple git merge.
Revert Approach
A more viable alternative in the scenario where you need to undo the changes introduced by some commits is git revert. The command basically introduces the opposite changes of the given commits. In your case, it would be something like git revert T1..T4. However, judging from your post, I'd say that you've already reset your local branch and at this point a git push --force is probably the easiest way to go on.
But, if you're in the situation where other developers have already based their work on those commits, you could bring back your local branch to T4 via git reflog. This command is often described as Git's time machine and allows you to know the commits that have been pointed by the HEAD ref. In this way, you could trace T4 and bring back your local branch to that state. At that point, you could launch git revert HEAD~3..HEAD and bring your local branch to the exact same state of T1 without changing the branch's history. This will allow you to push with no problems and avoid disrupting your colleagues' work.
#Tracing back T4
git reflog

a3e4ade (HEAD -> master) HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD~3
2044720 (origin/master) HEAD@{1}: commit: T4
3541183 HEAD@{2}: commit: T3
d94d0c3 HEAD@{3}: commit: T2
a3e4ade (HEAD -> master) HEAD@{4}: commit: T1
...
5723dcd HEAD@{5}: commit (initial): init commit

#Resetting the local branch to T4
git reset --hard HEAD@{1}

#Undoing the changes of the last 3 commits
git revert HEAD~3..HEAD


TL;DR
Run:
git reset --hard T1
git push --force-with-lease

Explanation
Commits in git are chained like Linked Lists. Every commit points to the one prior, except the first commit which has null parent. (side note: merge commits have two parents.)
Branches in git are just pointers. And there's a special pointer in git called HEAD. It points to where you currently stand.
    HEAD ->master
            |
            v
T1 <- T2 <- T3

Here, master branch is at T3. HEAD is pointing to master, meaning you're currently standing onmaster which, in turn, is at T3 commit.
Git repos are designed to work in a decenterlized fashion. By that I mean, you can work with your repo locally without the need to contact the server. Your local repo and the server repo are replicas. They sync with commands like fetch and push. Here's a pictorial representation of your local and server repos.
   HEAD ->master (origin/master)              master 
            |                                   | 
            v                                   v 
T1 <- T2 <- T3                      T1 <- T2 <- T3
                                                ^ 
                                                | 
                                              HEAD

  LOCAL REPO                              SERVER/ORIGIN


git on your local machine marks where master branch is pointing from server perspective using origin/master.
When you run git reset --hard T3, it repositions HEAD and the current branch, master in this case, to T3.
HEAD -> master  origin/master                          master 
          |           |                                   | 
          v           v                                   v 
          T1 <- T2 <- T3                      T1 <- T2 <- T3
                                                          ^ 
                                                          | 
                                                         HEAD

  LOCAL REPO                              SERVER/ORIGIN


Note that HEAD and master are repositioned, but origin/master is still pointing to where the server is pointing.
Now, when you push, git rejects because it sees that you are behind the server and you should get the rest of the commits on the branch master. To tell git that you know what you're doing you use --force-with-lease option:
git push --force-with-lease.
It tells git that you know what you're doing as long as you're aware of the changes from the server. It's even better to use than git push --force; because it results in failed push if your local repo is actually behind the server repo, saving you from destroying others' work.

Note: AFAIK HEAD would typically point to the branch (i.e. master instead of T4, git can just resolve that reference). If HEAD pointed to Tt, it would be a detached HEAD.

You are correct. My bad. Let me update my answer. Thank you!

Also it might be a good idea to note that force-pushing to shared branches may cause some headaches (and git reset --hard alsso overwrites uncommitted files as well as it can "remove" commits from a branch even though the latter are still in the reflog for some time)

Good idea! I'd love to add even more. But, obviously, the OP is a beginner and I don't want to overwhelm them with too much information. Trying to keep it as short and sweet as possible.
