How to undo commits after pushing them to the repository?
I was wondering how I can undo the files I pushed onto a repository? Is there an easy way to do this other than deleting the wrong files?
I pushed the wrong files onto GitHub and want to undo them and push the right files.

Please add more details to your question. What have you tried doing? Are those files not supposed to be there? Are they supposed to be there but be ignored by git? Do they have secret information that you need scrubbed from git?

Revert to previous commit locally and git push -f to overwrite history on the remote server

Fix your local branch and force push.  The commits will still exist in the remote, but the force push will make the remote branch point to a commit that does not contain them.

You can either reset and force push (as others have already said) or revert and then push. This question is similar to your problem. It should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78298390/override-current-code-with-specific-changelog/78298663#78298663

this question also answered here: How can I undo pushed commits using git?
You can revert individual commits with:
git revert <commit_hash>

This will create a new commit which reverts the changes of the commit you specified. Note that it only reverts that specific commit, and not commits that come after that. If you want to revert a range of commits, you can do it like this:
git revert <oldest_commit_hash>..<latest_commit_hash>

It reverts all the commits after <oldest_commit_hash> up to and including <latest_commit_hash>. Some versions of git also revert the <oldest_commit_hash> itself, so double check if that commit gets reverted or not. You can always drop the latest revert commit (which reverts the oldest commit) with g reset --hard HEAD~.
